# Bootstrap: Can't make a page responsive for all screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm using Vue.js to make a landing page for my project, it looks quite good on large screens but terrible on tablet and smartphone ones. I've tried to follow all the instruction on Bootstrap documentation to get the best result possible, but I'm totally lost on small screen. How can I modify it in order to show it correctly and clean on small screens?

```
<template>

  <div class="container-fluid m-0 p-0">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom">
  <a class="navbar-brand " href="http://exaple.com/">
  
    <img src="../assets/logo.png" width="40" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
      example.com
      </a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
       
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#sigUP" style="color:white;">Signin</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#mission" style="color:white;">Mission</a>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="home-page" class="full-height p-4">
      <div class="container pt-500">

        <div class="row pb-6 pt-20">
          <div class="col-lg-6  my-auto ">
            <div class="text-right text-down mb-3 d-block d-lg-none">
              <h1 class ="text-color text-right text-down">Hello,</h1>
              <h1 class="display-1 text-color text-right text-down">Betatester!</h1>
            </div>
            
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-6 my-auto pt-6">
            <div class="text-right text-down mb-3 d-none d-lg-block">
              <h1 class ="text-color text-right text-down">Hello,</h1>
              <h1 class="display-1 text-color text-right text-down" >Betatester!</h1>
            </div>
 </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

 

    <div id="about" class="bg-light p-3 p-md-5">
       <h1 class="display-1 text-color-about text-center"  >example.com is </h1>
      <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-lg">
            <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-left" >
            the socialnetwork for you
          </h1>
          <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-left text-color-about_p" >Freetime</h1>
          <img src="../assets/exam1.png" height="100">
          <img src="../assets/exam1.png" height="100">
          <img src="../assets/exam1.png" height="100">
        </div>
        
         <div class="col-lg">
          <img src="../assets/about.png" height="300" class="m-4">
        
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>







    <div id="marketplace" class=" p-4"> 
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg">
          <img src="../assets/marketplace.png" height="400">
         </div>
          <div class="col-lg">
            <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-right" >
<h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-right text-color-about_m" >MARKETPLACE</h1>
            
            where you can find all you need
            </h1>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>


  <div id="shops" class=" p-4"> 
        <div class="row">
          
            <div class="col-lg">
              <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-left" >
               the place where you can contact your
              <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-left text-color-about_s p-4" >FAVORITE </h1>
              <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-left text-color-about_p" >STORE</h1>
              
              </h1>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg">
            <img src="../assets/shop.png" height="400">
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>



      <div id="comp" class=" p-4"> 
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg">
          <img src="../assets/comp.png" height="400">
         </div>
          <div class="col-lg">
            <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-right" >
             be
            <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-right text-color-about_m" >COMPETITIVE</h1>
            blablablablablablablalbalba
            </h1>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>





    <div id="mission" class=" p-4"> 
        <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-lg">
              <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-left" style="display: inline-block" >
               the 
              <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-left text-color-about_s" style="display: inline-block" > MISSION </h1>
              </h1>
              <h3 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-left">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel dolor neque. Vivamus id ultrices nunc. Proin vulputate iaculis tortor ac rhoncus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus in lobortis diam, eu ullamcorper ante. Pellentesque sodales felis sit amet metus laoreet sodales. Proin auctor nulla vitae porta pretium. Nullam tempor blandit sem vitae finibus.
          </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg">
            <img src="../assets/mission.png" height="400">
          </div>
        </div>
        

      </div>


      <div id="betatest" class=" p-3"> 
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-lg">
          </div>
            <h1 class="ml-md-0 mr-md-0   text-center display-1">
              Why you'll be 
            
            <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-center  text-color-about_b display-1">
              Betatester?
            </h1>
            </h1>
            
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
          <div class="col-lg">
          <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-center" style="font-size: 4em;">
                be<h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-center" style="display: inline-block; color:white;font-size: 4em;font-size: 1.2em">BETATESTER</h1> helps us to make the best experience possible on example.com
          </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>

      <div id="sigUP" class=" p-2">
          <div class="row justify-content-center pd-8">
            <div class="col-lg pd-8">
              <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-center display-2">
                Become
               
                <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-center text-color-about_sn display-4">
                  a BETATESTER
                </h1>
              </h1>
            </div> 
          </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center pd-8">
            <div class="col-lg ">
              <img src="../assets/player.png">
              <div class="row justify-content-center pd-8">
                <div class="col-lg ">
                  <a href="/#/signupPlayer" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-custom align-self-end" role="button">Player</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg ">
              <img src="../assets/store.png">
              <div class="row justify-content-center pd-8">
                <div class="col-lg ">
                  <a href="/#/signupStore" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-customS " role="button">Store</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
<div id="contact" class="p-5">
      <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3">

        <div v-if="show_contact == true" class="col-lg-4" style="color:white">
          <h2>Hai una domanda?</h2>
          <p>Contact us!</p>

          <div v-if="contact_notice != ''" class="alert alert-warning">
            there's a problem. {{contact_notice}}
          </div>

          <form @submit.prevent="sendContactMessage()">
            <div class="form-group text-left ">
              <input v-model="contact_email"
                     type="email"
                     class="form-control"
                     placeholder="............"
                     >
              <textarea v-model="contact_message"
                        class="form-control mt-3"
                        placeholder="..........."
                        rows="5"
              ></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">send</button>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div v-else>
          <h3>mail sent correctly!</h3>
          <p>thanks for contact us!.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
<div id="footer" class=" p-4">
      <footer class="text-light p-4">
<small>&copy; 2020,example</small>
      </footer>
    </div>


  </div>

</template>

<style scoped>
  #home-page {
    background-color: #ff9e0b;
    background: url('../assets/bg_mt.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  #about {
    min-height: 40vh;
  }

  #contact {
    background-color: #252223;
  }

  #marketplace {
    background-color: #ff9e0b;
  }

  #comp {
    background-color: #ff9e0b;
  }

  #footer {
    background-color: #252223;
  }

  #betatest {
    background-color: #ff9e0b;
  }

  .navbar-custom { 
            background-color:  #ff9e0b; 
        } 
        /* Modify brand and text color */ 
          
        .navbar-custom .navbar-brand, 
        .navbar-custom .navbar-text { 
            color: white !important;
            font-size: 1.5em !important; 
        }

  .text-color{
      color:white;
      font-family: 'Mountserrat',sans-serif;
      font-weight: 600;
  }
  .text-color-about{
      color:#ff9e0b;
      font-family: 'Mountserrat',sans-serif;
      font-weight: 600;
  }
  .text-color-about_p{
      color:#ff9e0b;
      font-family: 'Mountserrat',sans-serif;
      font-weight: 800;
      font-size: 4em !important;
  }
  .text-color-about_s{
      color:#ff9e0b;
      font-family: 'Mountserrat',sans-serif;
      font-weight: 800;
      font-size: 3em !important;
  }
  .text-color-about_m{
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Mountserrat',sans-serif;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 3em !important;
  }
  .text-color-about_b{
      color:white;
      font-family: 'Mountserrat',sans-serif;
      align-self: center;
      font-weight: 800;
      font-size: 2em !important;
  }
  .text-color-about_sn{
      color:#ff9e0b;
      font-family: 'Mountserrat',sans-serif;
      align-self: center;
      font-weight: 800;
      font-size: 1em !important;
  }
  .bg-primary{
      color:#ff9e0b;
  }
  .bg-imgPlayer{
      contain: url(../assets/store-02.png);
      
  }
  .btn-customS{
      border-radius: 1rem;
      background-color: #f23838 !important;
  }
  .btn-custom{
      border-radius: 1rem;
      background-color: #ff9e0b !important;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: What I'm trying to point out is that you can't rely 100% on pre-determined @media queries, especially if you have any custom code if your website...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @media queries.

The built-in Bootstrap media queries breakpoints are found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/

You can also add your own and/or override the CSS values using !important

You will have to actually manually adjust for every major screen size namely tablet and mobile is a good start, but you can refine of course, iPhones, Android, Google Pixels, etc.

So that's what @media query looks like and you just put the CSS code specific to that width inside it like this:

```css
// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { 

  .some-element-class {
          width:85px; /* .... */
}
}
```

Comment: I'm new in html/css, so please excuse me for my questions. I've tried to implement your code in CSS changing "some-element-class" with my custom class "navbar-custom", but now , also in big screen mode, the navbar is cut. Can you provide me another example? Excuse me for my request but is confusing the first time

Comment: Yes you should use `max-width:` instead of `min-width` I didn't pay attention for the example sorry :)